# trying to add a second line in Highcharts spline

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i having problems adding a new line into the highchart spline.
i want a second line with different color is this possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/gc9n/uBxmz/1

```
 load: function ()
  {    
    var series1 = this.series[0];
    var series2 = this.series[1];
    setInterval(function () {   
    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time    
        y = Math.random() ; 
        c = Math.random();
    series1.addPoint([x, y], true, true);   
    series2.addPoint([x, c], true, true);   
    chart.redraw()
    }, 700);
```

Comment: Where You have Problem? in Your fiddle add data for other series

Comment: Yes my friend Muhammad look inside the fiddle even though i added this part it ignores , i can;t add a second line..                                   series1.addPoint([x, y], true, true);   
    series2.addPoint([x, c], true, true);   
    chart.redraw()

Comment: ok i thik i found it,, just look at the fiddle

Comment: So all works properly? 

In you solution you can replace series1.addPoint([x, y], true, true);   
    series2.addPoint([x, c], true, true);    with series1.addPoint([x, y], false, true);   
    series2.addPoint([x, c], true, true);   and animate points after adding last point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Just Change You Below Part of The code

```
   series: [{   
   name: ' Speed',       
   data: (function () {       
   var data = [],time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;        

   for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {    
   data.push({x: time + i * 1000,y:44});       
   }    
   return data;  
   })() },
   {
   name:'Second Series',
   data: // Add your data here
   }

  ]
```